# Can't get rid of mystery kernel

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, linux-kernel, grub2

Just noticed that despite having the kernel updated regularly, the version in use is quite outdated:

```
$ uname -a
Linux test 2.6.31-302-rs #7 SMP Thu Oct 29 22:57:03 UTC 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Strangely, this version of the kernel doesn't even appear to be installed:

```
$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-2.6.32-41-generic       2.6.32-41.90                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 2.6.32 on x86/x86_64
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-54-generic       3.13.0-54.91                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-54-generic 3.13.0-54.91                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                 3.13.0.54.61                     amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Also, there is no mention of 2.6 in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, so where does it come from, and how do I get the system to use the 3.13 kernel?

Comment: What's the nature of the server? VPS somewhere? Bare metal?

Comment: It's not so strange when you consider how some VM's are booted.  This is probably a xen base.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to be running an old first-generation Rackspace Cloud virtual server.

You have a couple of options:

1. Create a new PVHVM instance and move all your data to it from the original instance.
2. Update the old instance to boot with pvgrub. You will need to have Rackspace support complete this step for you after you [verify that the instance is bootable](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/using-a-custom-kernel-with-pv-grub).